# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is empty with Form.authentication in subfolder of website in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, httpcontext

I have a scenario that I have 3 different application

1. Calendar view(Web forms)
2. Web API(MVC)
3. MVC Application

I have hosted 1. and 2. on IIS in one website. As I also want to include 3. in same website but as Web api and MVC application contains Global.asax I created a sub virtual directory.

Example:
I have a website path as www.calendarview.com/login.aspx. This application(Calendar view(Web forms)) used form athentication. In web.config below is a code

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Index.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2440">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
```

Login.aspx

```
 if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(UserName.Text, UserPass.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, false);
                Session["username"] = UserName.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                Msg.Text = "Invalid User Name and/or Password";
            }
```

After login

```
var username = User?.Identity?.Name;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(Request.QueryString.ToString());
```

Now web API able to get HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

=====================================

Now coming to MVC application whose path is like www.calendarview.com/Masters/....

Website contains sub folder/virtual directory. Here I am not able to get HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Code is as below in MVC application

```
public class SessionTimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // strUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == null || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)))
            {

#if !DEBUG
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Global.GetLoginURLPath);
#endif
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        }
    }
```

How can I get  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in sub folder/directory on IIS with C#.net

Comment: Is your webapi and mvc in a different site in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

> Try the following approach to get the user in ASP.NET Identity, etc.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string username, int id)
{
    // get by username
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(username);

    // get by user id
    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Find(id);

    // get current user
    ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
        .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(Convert
        .ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));

    // and some other useful methods        
    if (user == null)
    {
        // creating user 
        user = new ApplicationUser();

        // fill in the user properties 
        user.UserName = "jdoe";
        user.Name = "John Doe";
        //...
        var result = UserManager.Create(user);

        // set default user group and roles
        var defaultGroup = "xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-tttt"; // Id of the ApplicationGroup
        groupManager.SetUserGroups(user.Id, new string[] { defaultGroup });
        groupManager.SetGroupRoles(newGroup.Id, new string[] { role.Name });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.